# Creating android phonegap maven project in eclipse

Tags: java, android, cordova

My first question is **"Is it possible to create a maven phonegap project in eclipse ?** " .

For the matter of fact i have tried to create one in eclipse and these are the steps followed :

1. Created a android maven project with archetype set to android release.
2. Now i have a compiled gwt project i simply copied the war content   (Html + Css + Js) along with cordova.js file to the assets/www folder of the android project .
3. Next added the cordova.jar(cordova 3.5.0) as maven dependency and also to the /libs folder of the project.
4. Added the config.xml file to res/xml folder .
5. Last extended the android main activity class from Cordova activity and did this `super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/MyHtml.html")`

So now my problem is , i am able to create the apk by running mvn clean install android:deploy goal , but this damm apk when i run on the device gives me

> "Unfortunately 'AppName' is Stopped "

error . What could be the issue with my approch ? Is there any way to find out what's going wrong is this case ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you should create a project using the CLI, then put your html + css + js then use the cli to add android platform and prepare it or build it and then if you really need to you can import the project in eclipse.

Comment: This could be obvious but here's what i did , i downloaded and installed node.js along with git client ,i am able to invoke 'npm' on command line but not 'cordova' after installing cordova module using npm utility of node.js i used this command to install cordova  " $ sudo npm install -g cordova "  and  hence unable to create an cordova application using CLI